# Como confirma o UPDATE com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Tem alguma função no PDO que permite verificar se o UPDATE concorreu com sucesso? Igual ao método 'lestInsertId()' é que usado para verificar se foi gerado uma nova ID em um tabela com auto incremento depois de um INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `rowCount`:

```
$stmt->rowCount();
```

Quando você faz um `SELECT`, ele retorna a quantidade de resultados, mas quando faz `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc ele retorna o número de linhas afetadas.

```
if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
   echo 'ocorreram alterações na tabela';
} else {
   echo 'nada foi alterado';
}
```

Notar que isto não tem nada a ver com testar se a *query* funcionou ou não por causa de erros. Para erros, você tem os métodos tradicionais.

A resposta é basicamente como confirmar se houve update ou não, os outros erros devem ser verificados sempre, de qualquer forma.

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Se estiver usando `MySQL`, tem uma opção ao inicializar o `PDO` que muda o comportamento do retorno de forma ao `rowCount` retornar valores mesmo se o `UPDATE` localizou as linhas, mas não alterou pelo valor ser igual:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $u, $p, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
```

Originalmente se voce faz um `UPDATE tabela SET valor = 0 WHERE id = 0;`, e o valor já era zero na tabela, isto não é contado como atualização, mesmo existindo `id` igual a zero. A propriedade `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` serve para mudar o comportamento, retornando o número localizado pelo `WHERE`, e não os valores efetivamente alterados.